# C# How to iterate through list for API URL call

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

I have this json data and have put it into a list:

```
{
"date": "2016-08-26",
"time_of_day": "14:19",
"request_time": "2016-08-26T14:19:59+01:00",
"station_name": "Derby",
"station_code": "DBY",
"departures": {
  "all": [
    {   
       "service": "22152000",
    },
    {
       "service": "22150000",
    },
    {
       "service": "22180008",
    }
  ]
}
}

dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
JArray items = new JArray();
items.Add(service["service"]);

int serviceLength = items.Count;
```

After this I would like to make a API call in a URLfor each individual item from the items list. This is what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
string moreJson = get_web_content("http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/service/" + items[i] + "/" + appID + "/" + appKey);
}
```

Thnak you for your help!

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: What is the connection between the json to the items array?  Are you trying to enumerate through the departures?

Comment: yes! the original json content has more objects within it but I am just interest in the service objects

Comment: the json content will also always be dynamic. And I am trying to iterate through each service object to then add each service object to a api url call dynamically

Comment: there's nothing known about some/most of the json content?  you can't map to a known type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try something like this?

```
if (content.departures != null)
        {
            var departureString = content.departures.ToString();
            departureString = Regex.Replace(departureString, @"[^\d|\:]", string.Empty);

            var items = departureString.Split(':');

            if (items != null && items.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(items[i]))
                    string moreJson = get_web_content("http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/service/" + items[i] + "/" + appID + "/" + appKey);
                }
            }

        }
```